# Detecting nodules in pulmonary images with vlfeat library (matlab)

Tags: image, matlab, svm, vlfeat

I'm trying to build a classifier in Matlab for nodule detection in pulmonary images. I'm using a linear svm with sift features calculated with the vlfeat library and I managed to classify the images. Now I'd need to highlight the nodules in the positive images. Can you suggest any way to do this?

Comment: Did you do any research on how to do it yourself? Please share your attempt to implement the issue first, so others can help if you are stuck.

Comment: Also, please read [ask] and specially [mcve]